# VLOOKUP with multiple value key

Tags: excel

For those with an SQL background, I am trying to do a kind of "JOIN" with multiple criteria.

Here is my worksheet :

```
TABLE 1
┌──────┬─────────┬─────┐
│DOMAIN│BRAND    │VALUE│
├──────┼─────────┼─────┤
│SKI   │NIKE     │ 42  │
│SKI   │GOPRO    │ 94  │
│SKI   │RIP CURL │ 78  │
│SNOW  │NIKE     │ 38  │
│SURF  │BILLABONG│ 13  │
│SURF  │HURLEY   │ 99  │
│SNOW  │NIKE     │ 72  │
└──────┴─────────┴─────┘

TABLE 2
┌──────┬─────────┐
│DOMAIN│BRAND    │
├──────┼─────────┤
│SNOW  │NIKE     │
│SURF  │HURLEY   │
│SKI   │FOO      │
└──────┴─────────┘
```

I want to highlight rows in Table1 that are in Table2
(Here is should highlight rows 4 and 6).

I tried a VLOOKUP but it only takes one key as search argument. I also tried a combination of IF and MATCH, but it would highlight every rows of a brand if its name is in TABLE 2.

Do you have any hints for me please ?

[Edit] Before duplicate: I found this topic: [Excel - VLOOKUP with multiple criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22083331/excel-vlookup-with-multiple-criteria)
but the answer does not seems to work anymore.

Comment: Create a conditional format rule that use the [COUNTIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-53C4DC8E-0E5B-4E32-93DF-9CA5E7DA89ED).

Comment: btw, thanks for noting that broken link in the other topic. I've added an update answer to the thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A proper SQL-like join will also highlight row 7.
That you can achieve for example with `SUMPRODUCT()`.
Putting the first table with the headers in `A1` and the second with the headers in `A12` you can do the following:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$13:$A$15 = A2) * 1,
            ($B$13:$B$15 = B2) * 1)
```

This creates an array of TRUE/FALSE whether the values equal the ones in table 2 and multiplies them by 1 converting the booleans to 1/0.
Then  it's multiplying the rows of 1/0 values and sums them (can be done with any number of columns).
Assuming the values in table 2 are unique you will get 0 or 1 as a result for every row in Table 1.
These you can then compare to 1 to get a Boolean value again for your conditional formatting.