# Compare multiple columns in Excel and fetch the data from other columns if it is true

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, vba

I want to compare around 5 columns from sheet1 against sheet2. If condition satisfies then fetch the data from 6th column from sheet1 to 6th column of sheet2. Sorry if the question is trivial or repeated.
[sheet1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alc1o.jpg)

[sheet2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1RF0.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel - VLOOKUP with multiple criteria](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22083331/excel-vlookup-with-multiple-criteria)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to compare each column value in sheet1 to corresponding column value in sheet2 then you can use array formula as below:

In cell 'F2' in sheet2 enter the following formula and hit 'Ctrl+Shift+Enter' instead of Enter.

```
=IF(AND(Sheet1!A2:E2=Sheet2!A2:E2),Sheet1!F2,"")
```

Then drag the formula down using fill handle