# Excel Formula - How to get the highest 2 values of a cell based on another cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need some help with the following requirement:

**Raw Data**

```
            A            B            C
      -------------------------------------
   1 |     Opp     |   Vendor    |  Amount |
     |-------------|-------------|---------|
   2 |     101     |   Vendor1   | 100000  |
   3 |     101     |   Vendor2   |   5000  |
   4 |     103     |   Vendor1   |  30000  |
   5 |     103     |   Vendor2   |   5000  |
   6 |     103     |   Vendor3   |  50000  |
```

**Output Table**

```
            A             B           C         D         E
      ---------------------------------------------------------
   1 |     Opp     |  MainVendor | Amount1 | 2Vendor | Amount2 |
     |-------------|-------------|---------|---------|---------|
   2 |     101     |   Vendor1   | 100000  | Vendor2 |  5000   |
   3 |     103     |   Vendor3   |  50000  | Vendor1 |  30000  |
```

- **MainVendor**: Vendor with the highest Amount
- **Amount1**: Amount for MainVendor
- **2Vendor**: Second highest vendor
- **Amount2**: Amount for 2Vendor

I was only able to get Amount1 value using the following array formula:

```
{=MAX(IF(A:A=[@[Opp]];C:C))}
```

in column C.

I'm failing to get the values for column **B**, **D** & **E**.

Comment: What version of Excel?

Comment: Hi Ron! I'm using excel 2010 version

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I'm pretty sure this question is a near-duplicate of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22083331/excel-vlookup-with-multiple-criteria). There was another duplicate today. Must be one of those days.

Comment: @MaycoDuran I have deleted my answer because the examples you give of your desired output, in your [link](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AiOPHAAd8ObahGHVmKCGiHC9PhE_), are using a different logic than what I inferred from your example above.  You need to clarify things.  The formulas I gave check the entire Amount column to determine the values, but the results you desire clearly do not.  Now that I have shown you the `LARGE` function, hopefully you can work up something that comes close to what you want.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Thanks for the tip, and sorry for my bad exposure of the requirements, English is not my first language and I'm trying my best! Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution - may be a bit convoluted so happy to hear constructive criticism if people can refactor the formulas.

To get the `Amount1`, `Amount2` values you can use:

```
=INDEX(LARGE($C$2:$C$10*--($A$2:$A$10=$A13),1),1)
```

Where:

- `$C$2:$C$10` are the values from the `Amount` column
- multiplied by `--($A$2:$A$10=$A13)` - meaning `{1;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;0} * {100000;5000;30000;5000;50000;45000;50000;40000;51000}` - this has the impact of eliminating values in the `Amount` column that do not correspond to the `Opp` of the row.
- The `LARGE` function then just picks 1st largest of `100000` and `5000` as the other values in the array are now `0`.
- to get 2nd largest, 3rd largest etc you suppy `2`, `3` etc into the `LARGE` function
- `LARGE` function is wrapped in `INDEX` to get the actual value out as I believe its returning it as an 1-element array (although this isn't clear with the formula inspector)

Sample:

[image]

To get `MainVendor` and `Vendor2` values you can use:

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$10,INDEX(MATCH(LARGE($C$2:$C$10*--($A$2:$A$10=$A13),1),$C$2:$C$10*--($A$2:$A$10=$A13),0),1))
```

Which is:

- `$B$2:$B$10` are the values from the `Vendor` column
- the index is retrieved by using `MATCH` on the ***same formula*** used for `AmountX` against its own source array
- the `MATCH` is wrapped in another `INDEX` to get the actual value out as, once again, I think the value is being returned as a 1-element array

Sample:

[image]

I created another set of `Opp` values and the formula works with some duplicate values in the `Amount` column but for different `Opp`s.

Comment: Hey Robin, you're awesome, I'll give it a try tomorrow and come back with my results. Thank you very much! MD

Comment: Thank you Robin, works great! Sorry for the delay on testing as I was on my holidays! :)

Comment: In the case where vendors have the same "Amount", how can I fetch the other? I'm getting the same "Vendor" in this cases. Thanks!

Comment: The example of Opp 199, Vendor2 and Amount of 50,000 covered that, I thought?